# Changing EventSource in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to pass a parameter through the URL to the php code, however, it seems that in the function body of the on message event, I can't change the source. Here's the code below:

```
var source = new EventSource("get_message.php?latest_chat_ID=0");
var i = 0;
    $(source).on("message", function (event) {
        var data = event.originalEvent.data;

        ++i;

        source = new EventSource("get_message.php?latest_chat_ID=" + i);
        // $.post("get_message.php", {latest_chat_ID: 0}, function (data, status) {});

        $("#messages").html($("#messages").html() + data);
    });
```

I was wondering -

1. How do I rectify this problem?
2. Are there other ways to send data to a PHP page? (I contemplated using the $.post{} jQuery function, but that will execute the script twice - once from firing the EventSource event and once from the .post{} request?)

I also understand that alternative technologies exist, such as WebSockets and libraries such as node.js, that are better suited for bidirectional communication. However, most of my base code is written with an SSE implementation in mind, and I'd like to stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using SSE, I think you'll need to rewrite what you have similar to what is below. The reason what you have right now doesn't work is because you are only listening to the first `EventSource`, and just changing the variable. The variable is not reused by jQuery when you change it. Plus, I probably would skip using jQuery for that since it's going to try and cache things you don't want cached.

```
var listenToServer = function(i) {
  source = new EventSource("get_message.php?latest_chat_ID=" + i);
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    var data = event.originalEvent.data;
    $messages.html($messages.html() + data);
    listenToServer(i + 1);
  }
},
$messages = $('#messages'),
source;

listenToServer(0);
```

I also went ahead and cached `$('#messages')` so you're not creating new objects over and over. Left `source` outside of the function so that you don't have to worry as much about garbage collection with the various `EventSource`s.